# WatchOS app cannot start with error Domain: "IDELaunchErrorDomain Code: 15" on Xcode 11 beta

Tags: watchos-5

Want to run app under watchOS getting error under Xcode beta:
Domain: IDELaunchErrorDomain Code: 15 Failure Reason: Build and Run launch failed as the app to run does not appear to be known by the system.

Comment: Same error here !! (under iOS13 release). Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I just found a solution: Delete all Schemes (under Top left: Mange Schemes... - delete all of them with the '-'Sign). Then add the Schemes again with the '+'Sign under Manage Schemes.... After doing so it works !

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Anybody find another solution? This still happens in the non-beta release.

Comment: Same problem here on Xcode `Version 11.1 (11A1027)`. Regenerating the schemes didn't work for me too.

Comment: Facing same issue. Managing schemes didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

My solution was to add to watch app scheme iOS target like in screenshot:
[image]

However I reported to Apple about such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after modifying the bundle identifier.
Following these steps works for me:

- Delete all the Schemes
- Select the **WatchKit App** target and under `General > Embedded Content` remove the **WatchKit Extension**
- Select the **WatchKit Extension** target and under `Info > NSExtension > NSExtensionAttributes > WKAppBundleIdentifier` make sure it is the same identifier the **WatchKit App**
- Clean Build (just in case)
- Select again the **WatchKit App** target and under `General > Embedded Content` add the **WatchKit Extension**
- Add a new Scheme for the **WatchKit App**
- Edit the new Scheme and in `Build` add a the target for: (credits to [Evgeny Zrorin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58083094/4691224))

  - The **iOS App** target if your **WatchKit App** is a companion of an iOS App
  - The **iOS** target generated by Xcode if your **WatchKit App** is a standalone App

You must have 2 targets in your `Scheme > Build`, run your app and good luck

Answer (score 0):

With your WatchKit app selected under your targets, go to 'Build Phases', expand the 'Dependencies' and the 'Embed App Extensions' sections and make sure that the correct Watchkit App Extension is present there. If you duplicated your target, it is possible that an old unrelated WatchKit extension sitting over there is creating the problem.